# How can you insert with PDO then return the `lastInsertId()` in the same function?

Tags: php, pdo

How can you insert with PDO then return the `lastInsertId()` that was created?  This can be done inside the function, but I either way I would like to get the `lastInsertId()` outside the function.

```
function insert_PDO($item1, $item2){

        $params =   array(
                        ":item1"        =>      $item1 ,
                        ":item2"        =>      $item2 
                    );

         $sql = "INSERT INTO table                  (column1,   column2)
                VALUES                              (:item1,    :item2)
            ";

    //return $this->insert($sql, $params);    //this one works

    //now trying this, want to return 

            $insertitems    = $this->insert($sql, $params);  
            $item_ID        = $this->lastInsertId();  
            return ($insertitems, $item_ID) ;  //does not work
}

protected function insert($sql, $params)
{
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute($params);
}

// I tried this too with the original insert:

    $results        =       $createInsert   ->  insert_PDO($item1, $item2);
    $lastid = $results[0];

    foreach($results1 as $row){
        $auditVID = $row[ID];
        $auditVID = $row[0];
    }
```

Comment: `return [$insertitems, $item_ID];` as array

Comment: So like this?   $insertitems    = $this->insert($sql, $params);  
            $item_ID        = $this->lastInsertId();  
            return [$insertitems, $item_ID] ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement

```
return ($insertitems, $item_ID) ;
```

will cause syntax error.

If you want to return several values - use array:

```
$insertitems    = $this->insert($sql, $params);  
$item_ID        = $this->lastInsertId();  
return array($insertitems, $item_ID) ;
// or for newer php versions:
return [$insertitems, $item_ID];
```

Comment: I am not sure why but $insertitems works, but the last $item_ID        = $this->lastInsertId();  does not in this statement.  The array does show when I comment out $item_ID= $this->lastInsertId(); otherwise no output.

Comment: I had to change it to:     $auditVID = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();    Then it works.  :)